# Как сделать постепенную смену картинки (с затемнением или анимацией наезжания) в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qstackedwidget, слайд-шоу

Можно ли сделать плавный переход от одной картинки к другой через `QPixmap`? Или это стоит делать другими способами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изображение карусели (очень крутое приложение).

Скопируйте три модуля. Создайте рядом каталог/папку **`image`**
(так настроено в приложении, но вы можете это изменить).
Набросайте в эту папку (**`image`**) изображений и запустите **main.py**

**main.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QEasingCurve, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QSizePolicy
from UiImageSlider import Ui_Form  


class ImageSliderWidget(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ImageSliderWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Инициализировать тип кривой анимации
        curve_types = [(n, c) for n, c in QEasingCurve.__dict__.items()
                       if isinstance(c, QEasingCurve.Type)]
        curve_types.sort(key=lambda ct: ct[1])
        curve_types = [c[0] for c in curve_types]
        self.comboBoxEasing.addItems(curve_types)

        # Слоты связующих сигналов
        self.spinBoxSpeed.valueChanged.connect(self.stackedWidget.setSpeed)
        self.comboBoxEasing.currentTextChanged.connect(self.setEasing)
        self.radioButtonHor.toggled.connect(self.setOrientation)
        self.radioButtonVer.toggled.connect(self.setOrientation)
        self.pushButtonPrev.clicked.connect(self.stackedWidget.slideInPrev)
        self.pushButtonNext.clicked.connect(self.stackedWidget.slideInNext)
        self.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.autoStart)
        self.pushButtonStop.clicked.connect(self.autoStop)
        
        self.show()

        extensions = ('.jpg', '.png', '.jpeg',)

        # Добавить страницу изображения
# ваши изображения находятся в  vvvvv  каталоге image (например)
        for name in os.listdir('image'):
            filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(name)
            if not file_extension in extensions:
                continue
            
            label = QLabel(self.stackedWidget)
            label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            label.setMinimumSize(240, 160)                                    
            
            label.setPixmap(
# ваши изображения  в    vvvvvv  каталоге image (например)
                QPixmap('image/' + name).scaled(
                    self.stackedWidget.size(),   
                    Qt.KeepAspectRatio, 
                    Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            )
            label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label)

    def autoStart(self):
        self.pushButtonNext.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButtonPrev.setEnabled(False)
        self.stackedWidget.autoStart()

    def autoStop(self):
        self.pushButtonNext.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButtonPrev.setEnabled(True)
        self.stackedWidget.autoStop()

    def setEasing(self, name):
        self.stackedWidget.setEasing(getattr(QEasingCurve, name))

    def setOrientation(self, checked):
        hor = self.sender() == self.radioButtonHor
        if checked:
            self.stackedWidget.setOrientation(
                Qt.Horizontal if hor else Qt.Vertical)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = ImageSliderWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UiImageSlider.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(656, 612)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.stackedWidget = SlidingStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        
        self.spinBoxSpeed = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.groupBox)
        self.spinBoxSpeed.setMinimum(100)
        self.spinBoxSpeed.setMaximum(5000)
        self.spinBoxSpeed.setProperty("value", 500)
        self.spinBoxSpeed.setObjectName("spinBoxSpeed")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.spinBoxSpeed)
        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        
        self.groupBox_2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        
        self.radioButtonHor = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.radioButtonHor.setChecked(True)
        self.radioButtonHor.setObjectName("radioButtonHor")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButtonHor)
        
        self.radioButtonVer = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.groupBox_2)
        self.radioButtonVer.setObjectName("radioButtonVer")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.radioButtonVer)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_2)
        
        self.groupBox_3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_3.setObjectName("groupBox_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        
        self.comboBoxEasing = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox_3)
        self.comboBoxEasing.setObjectName("comboBoxEasing")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.comboBoxEasing)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_3)
        
        self.groupBox_4 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_4.setObjectName("groupBox_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.pushButtonPrev = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_4)
        self.pushButtonPrev.setObjectName("pushButtonPrev")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButtonPrev)
        self.pushButtonNext = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_4)
        self.pushButtonNext.setObjectName("pushButtonNext")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButtonNext)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_4)
        
        self.groupBox_5 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(Form)
        self.groupBox_5.setObjectName("groupBox_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupBox_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.pushButtonStart = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_5)
        self.pushButtonStart.setObjectName("pushButtonStart")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButtonStart)
        self.pushButtonStop = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.groupBox_5)
        self.pushButtonStop.setObjectName("pushButtonStop")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.pushButtonStop)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox_5)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Анимация карусели изображений"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Скорость анимации:"))
        self.groupBox_2.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Направление анимации:"))
        self.radioButtonHor.setText(_translate("Form", "горизонтальное"))
        self.radioButtonVer.setText(_translate("Form", "вертикальное"))
        self.groupBox_3.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Тип кривой анимации:"))
        self.groupBox_4.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Показать страницу:"))
        self.pushButtonPrev.setText(_translate("Form", "Предыдущая страница"))
        self.pushButtonNext.setText(_translate("Form", "Следующая страница"))
        self.groupBox_5.setTitle(_translate("Form", "Карусель:"))
        self.pushButtonStart.setText(_translate("Form", "Карусель начинается"))
        self.pushButtonStop.setText(_translate("Form", "Карусельная остановка"))

from SlidingStackedWidget import SlidingStackedWidget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**SlidingStackedWidget.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtProperty, QEasingCurve, QPoint, \
    QPropertyAnimation, QParallelAnimationGroup, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QStackedWidget


class SlidingStackedWidget(QStackedWidget):
    LEFT2RIGHT, RIGHT2LEFT, TOP2BOTTOM, BOTTOM2TOP, AUTOMATIC = range(5)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pnow = QPoint(0, 0)
        # Скорость анимации
        self._speed = 500
        # Текущий индекс
        self._now = 0
        # Текущий индекс автоматического режима
        self._current = 0
        # Следующий индекс
        self._next = 0
        # Включить
        self._active = 0
        # Анимация (по умолчанию - пейзаж)
        self._orientation = Qt.Horizontal
        # Тип кривой анимации
        self._easing = QEasingCurve.Linear
        
        # Инициализировать анимацию
        self._initAnimation()

    def setSpeed(self, speed=500):
        """ Установите скорость анимации
        :param speed:       Значение скорости по умолчанию - 500
        :type speed:        int
        """
        self._speed = speed

    @pyqtProperty(int, fset=setSpeed)
    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    def setOrientation(self, orientation=Qt.Horizontal):
        """ Задайте направление анимации (горизонтальной и вертикальной)
        :param orientation:    Направление (Qt.Horizontal или Qt.Vertical)
        :type orientation:     http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Orientation-enum
        """
        self._orientation = orientation

    @pyqtProperty(int, fset=setOrientation)
    def orientation(self):
        return self._orientation

    def setEasing(self, easing=QEasingCurve.OutBack):
        """ Задайте тип кривой анимации
        :param easing:    По умолчанию используется QEasingCurve.OutBack
        :type easing:     http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeasingcurve.html#Type-enum
        """
        self._easing = easing

    @pyqtProperty(int, fset=setEasing)
    def easing(self):
        return self._easing

    def slideInNext(self):
        """ Слайд на следующую страницу """
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if now < self.count() - 1:
            self.slideInIdx(now + 1)
            self._current = now + 1

    def slideInPrev(self):
        """ Слайд на предыдущую страницу """
        now = self.currentIndex()
        if now > 0:
            self.slideInIdx(now - 1)
            self._current = now - 1

    def slideInIdx(self, idx, direction=4):
        """ Слайд к указанному серийному номеру
        :param idx:               Серийный номер
        :type idx:                int
        :param direction:         Направление, по умолчанию автоматически  AUTOMATIC=4
        :type direction:          int
        """
        if idx > self.count() - 1:
            direction = self.TOP2BOTTOM if self._orientation == Qt.Vertical else self.RIGHT2LEFT
            idx = idx % self.count()
        elif idx < 0:
            direction = self.BOTTOM2TOP if self._orientation == Qt.Vertical else self.LEFT2RIGHT
            idx = (idx + self.count()) % self.count()
        self.slideInWgt(self.widget(idx), direction)

    def slideInWgt(self, widget, direction):
        """ Слайд к указанному виджету
        :param widget:        QWidget, QLabel, etc...
        :type widget:         QWidget Base Class
        :param direction:     направление
        :type direction:      int
        """
        if self._active:
            return
        self._active = 1
        _now = self.currentIndex()
        _next = self.indexOf(widget)
        if _now == next:
            self._active = 0
            return

        w_now = self.widget(_now)
        w_next = self.widget(_next)

        # Направление
        if _now < _next:
            directionhint = self.TOP2BOTTOM if self._orientation == Qt.Vertical else self.RIGHT2LEFT
        else:
            directionhint = self.BOTTOM2TOP if self._orientation == Qt.Vertical else self.LEFT2RIGHT
        if direction == self.AUTOMATIC:
            direction = directionhint

        # Вычислить смещение
        offsetX = self.frameRect().width()
        offsetY = self.frameRect().height()
        w_next.setGeometry(0, 0, offsetX, offsetY)

        if direction == self.BOTTOM2TOP:
            offsetX = 0
            offsetY = -offsetY
        elif direction == self.TOP2BOTTOM:
            offsetX = 0
        elif direction == self.RIGHT2LEFT:
            offsetX = -offsetX
            offsetY = 0
        elif direction == self.LEFT2RIGHT:
            offsetY = 0

        # Переместите следующий виджет с областью отображения
        pnext = w_next.pos()
        pnow  = w_now.pos()
        self._pnow = pnow

        # Перемещение в указанное место и отображение
        w_next.move(pnext.x() - offsetX, pnext.y() - offsetY)
        w_next.show()
        w_next.raise_()

        self._animnow.setTargetObject(w_now)
        self._animnow.setDuration(self._speed)
        self._animnow.setEasingCurve(self._easing)
        self._animnow.setStartValue(QPoint(pnow.x(), pnow.y()))
        self._animnow.setEndValue(
            QPoint(offsetX + pnow.x(), offsetY + pnow.y()))

        self._animnext.setTargetObject(w_next)
        self._animnext.setDuration(self._speed)
        self._animnext.setEasingCurve(self._easing)
        self._animnext.setStartValue(
            QPoint(-offsetX + pnext.x(), offsetY + pnext.y()))
        self._animnext.setEndValue(QPoint(pnext.x(), pnext.y()))

        self._next = _next
        self._now = _now
        self._active = 1
        self._animgroup.start()

    def _initAnimation(self):
        """ Инициализируйте переменные анимации текущей страницы 
            и следующей страницы  """
        # Текущая анимация страницы
        self._animnow = QPropertyAnimation(
            self, propertyName=b'pos', duration=self._speed,
            easingCurve=self._easing)
        # Анимация следующей страницы
        self._animnext = QPropertyAnimation(
            self, propertyName=b'pos', duration=self._speed,
            easingCurve=self._easing)
        # Группа параллельной анимации
        self._animgroup = QParallelAnimationGroup(
            self, finished=self.animationDoneSlot)
        self._animgroup.addAnimation(self._animnow)
        self._animgroup.addAnimation(self._animnext)

    def setCurrentIndex(self, index):
        # Переопределить переключатель анимации
        self.slideInIdx(index)

    def setCurrentWidget(self, widget):
        # Переопределить переключатель анимации
        super(SlidingStackedWidget, self).setCurrentWidget(widget)
        self.setCurrentIndex(self.indexOf(widget))

    def animationDoneSlot(self):
        """ Функция обработки конца анимации """
        # Поскольку метод setCurrentIndex перезаписан, 
        # здесь используется метод самого родительского класса.
        QStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self, self._next)
        w = self.widget(self._now)
        w.hide()
        w.move(self._pnow)
        self._active = 0

    def autoStop(self):
        """ Остановить автовоспроизведение"""
        if hasattr(self, '_autoTimer'):
            self._autoTimer.stop()

    def autoStart(self, msec=3000):
        """ Автоматическая карусель
        :param time: Время, по умолчанию 3000, 3 секунды
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_autoTimer'):
            self._autoTimer = QTimer(self, timeout=self._autoStart)
        self._autoTimer.stop()
        self._autoTimer.start(msec)

    def _autoStart(self):
        if self._current == self.count():
            self._current = 0
        self._current += 1
        self.setCurrentIndex(self._current)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]