# Как отобрать виджет у родителя и вывести в другое окно?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть окно с несколькими tabwidget, как при нажатии на кнопку в этом окне отобрать у родителя этот виджет и вывести его в другое окно?

Comment: smitzz, sorry, не надо ничего отбирать. Зачем вам второе окно, неужели для того чтобы у него (второго окна) что-то отобрать? Вы что-то делаете не так. Расскажите поподробнее, что вы хотите сделать в вашем приложении и покажите его.

Comment: S. Nick, хочу сделать слайд-шоу, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку первого окна с табами, все эти табы отображались в другом окне , их можно было переключать кнопками

Comment: smitzz, я не понимаю зачем вы манипулируете окнами. Если вы  хотите сделать слайд-шоу - рекомендую изучить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1380923/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2/1381593#1381593